# using Python to retrieve formatted strings from excel cell

Tags: excel, string, formatting, string-formatting, openpyxl

I'm trying to pull a string from an excel cell that will retain it's formatting when executed in Python. For example. I'm only a week into learning this (and this is my first post on stackoverflow), please forgive any errors of convention in my code or post.

The variable 'name' is global and is defined through input earlier in the program. Everything works fine when the cell contents are defined in the program instead (ex: question = f"Hello {name} returns exactly what i expect, with the variable value swapped out for {name}).

I am pulling the correct workbook, sheet and cell (1,1), and the cell's contents are: Hello {name}
I've also tried: f"Hello {name}"

```
Input:
import openpyxl
from gtts import gTTS
import os

def speak(question):
    language = 'en'
    myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
    myobj.save("q.mp3")
    os.system("q.mp3")

path = "wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
question = f"{sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value}"
speak(question)

Output: 
Hello {name}
```

I've tried the above format of question = f"(...)" as well as without the formatting. I've also tried leaving the sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value as is without formatting the string.   Nothing has worked for me yet, any insight would be greatly appreciated. This community has been an amazing resource so far! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `question = eval('f'+f'"{sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value}"')`

Comment: I tried it out, but it returned the same output as  I had before. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

To use a **dynamically created format string**, use the **eval** function.

This example may help. It creates an excel file with a formatted cell value, then retrieves the format string and creates an final output string using the `eval` function.

```
import openpyxl as px

# create workbook
wb = px.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(1,1).value='hello {xxx}'  # format string
wb.save("extest.xlsx")

# retrieve workbook
wb = px.load_workbook('extest.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

v = ws.cell(1,1).value   # hello {xxx}

xxx = 'python'

print(v)   # hello {xxx}
print(eval('f"' + v + '"'))  # hello python
print(eval('f"' + ws.cell(1,1).value + '"'))  # hello python
print(eval(f'f"{ws.cell(1,1).value}"'))  # hello python
```

Output

```
hello {xxx}
hello python
hello python
hello python
```

Comment: FANTASTIC!  Thank you so much.  I was able to see the logic behind what you did as well.  I'm quite new at this, so I'm still not sure what I was trying wasn't working that way I hoped. Thanks again